# Problemas con crystal reports en windows 10 (cliente)

Tags: crystal-reports, windows10

Amigos, tengo problemas al tratar de generar un reporte en windows10. 
La aplicación es en vb.net 2013 (winforms), estoy utilizando las dlls de `cristal reports 13.0.3500.X.`

En esta aplicación existen unos reportes que ejecutan packages en la base de datos (**oracle**), y otros que reciben un dataset con la informacion.

La aplicación se desarrollo en un equipo con windows7 de 64 bits, en este equipo funcionan correctamente todos los reportes, pero al instalar la aplicación en un equipo (cliente) con windows10, no funcionan los reportes que ejecutan packages en la base de datos.

El error que aparece es:

> "*Error en el archivo test{QWEQWEDASD..}.rpt: no se pudo cargar la información de la base de dato*".

¿Saben a que se debe? agradezco su ayuda. Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el error es claro no se puede cargar informacion de la base de datos por lo que debes validar la conexion, si el error persiste debes entonces validar el archivo asociado.

Answer (score 0):

en tu app.config, al final reemplaza:

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=4.6.1"/>
</startup>
```

Por esto:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero el framenwork que estoy utilizando es 4.5  uso:   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=4.0"/>
</startup>
 o   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=4.5"/>
</startup>

Comment: de nada, intenta :D

Comment: fredyfx, hice la prueba y aparece el mismo error   :(